# How do I sign in using a passkey on a remote pc (RDP)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, remote-desktop, bluetooth, passkey

I've a PC 1 at work where I can sign in into e.g.: GitHub using a passkey which is stored on my iPhone. Bluetooth has two activated on my iPhone and on my PC 1.

I've a PC 2 at home where I can sign in as well into GitHub using a passkey and my iPhone.

But I've I do a remote desktop connection from PC 2 to PC 1 using RDP, e.g.: home office, and I want to sign in on PC 1 using a passkey it fails because I sit in front of PC 2. I think it's because there can no Bluetooth connection established between PC 1 and my iPhone.

Any way to sign in on PC 1 using RDP and a passkey? Is there a way to redirect Bluetooth from PC 2 to PC 1 over RDP?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it out.

For RDP connection you need to allow
[WebAuthn redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/configure-device-redirections).

On PC 2 you need at least Windows 11 version 23H2, then the following dialog is shown on PC 2 when you want to sign on PC 1 over RDP using a passkey:

[image]

In the above dialog you can choose iPhone.

If PC 2 is running Windows 10, then only the following dialog is shown

[image]

In the above dialog there is no option to select iPhone.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-authentication-passwordless-security-key.

The QR code shown by the browser, e.g.: Chrome, is not working over RDP.

Comment: FYI: On server 2019 (1809), webauthn redirection is not supported for passkeys. Nice, isn't it? And this is how MS handles feedback: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1528486/why-would-windows-server-2019-rds-not-support-pass